# Changing an element type using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, types, element

I have the the following code:

```
$('#theForm').on('click', 'button', function(e){
var attrs = { };

var str =e.target.id;
var newStr = str.substring(0, str.length-1);

$("#file01b").replaceWith(function () {
attrs.text = $(this).text();
return $("<a />", attrs);
});

var field= document.getElementById(newStr);
field.value= field.defaultValue;
document.getElementById(newStr).style.display = "none";
});
```

**All the code:** http://jsfiddle.net/K9eWL/3/

and when I click on the first "Remove File" button it works fine, so I tried to make it automatically, in order it works for all the buttons:

```
$('#theForm').on('click', 'button', function(e){
var attrs = { };

var str =e.target.id;
var newStr = str.substring(0, str.length-1);

$("#str").replaceWith(function () {
attrs.text = $(this).text();
return $("<a />", attrs);
});

var field= document.getElementById(newStr);
field.value= field.defaultValue;
document.getElementById(newStr).style.display = "none";
});
```

**All the code:** http://jsfiddle.net/K9eWL/3/

but it doens't work, where is the error?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `doesn't work` is not a replacement for a concise  explanation of what you expect your code to do

Comment: If you're using jQuery, use jQuery. `document.getElementById(newStr).style.display = "none";` should be `$('#'+newStr).hide()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about, instead of:

```
$("#file01b").replaceWith(function () {
```

You use:

```
$("#"+e.target.id).replaceWith(function () {
```

Check [your fiddle, updated](http://jsfiddle.net/K9eWL/4/).

**Note:** If the above is fine, then `$(e.target).replaceWith(function () {` will [work as well](http://jsfiddle.net/K9eWL/5/).

Comment: ooohh what a mistake! Thank you sir. :)

Comment: Also, change the line to `return $("<a />");` so the words "Return File" are removed.

Comment: No, I cannot do that, I need it, because, now I'm changing the text in order to show: File removed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

'this.id' also works.

```
$("#"+this.id).replaceWith(function () {
```